# ContentPane inside AccordionContainer ignoring height

Tags: accordion, dojo

I want to have an accordion container with the top content pane only going down 300 px so that the user can easily click on the next header to bring up the full content pane.  For some reason the top ContentPane (Search Query Accordion Pane) is ignoring the height value I gave it in the style.  Anyone know why?

Thanks

```
<!-- Search Accordian Container -->
            <div id="accordion" dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">

                <!-- Search Query Accordian Pane -->
                <div style="height:300px; background-color: #F2EFED;" title="Search Query" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" selected="true" >
                    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" 
                           size="30" /><br/>
                    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" 
                           size="30" /><br/>
                    <label for="middle_initial">Middle Initial:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="middle_initial" id="middle_initial" 
                           size="1" /><br/>
                </div>

                <!-- Search Results Accordian View -->
                <div class="searchAccordianPane" title="Search Results" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">
                    <img src="http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/accordion/every-picture.jpg" class="image" />
                    <p>Roderick "Rod" David Stewart, CBE (born January 10, 1945), is a singer and songwriter...</p>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use that behaviour with AccordionPane... I think all the pane should have the same size.
One trick could be to use a titlePane for the limited size, then accordionPane for the other panes.